# Fantasy novel with female protagonist and mages who can be drained of power by a cut?

Tags: story-identification, magic

I believe it was a standalone, but possibly 2 books. The main character was a female. The mages in the story exploded when they died unless they were completely drained of power first.  They could be drained by making a small cut and then the other mage touching the cut and draining them (to the extent it would kill them). A large portion of the book was main character's training to use magic at a school where thy would basically put up magical shields and duel each other. I believe I read it in late 90's to early 2000.

Comment: Almost certainly Trudi Canavan's [*Black Magician* trilogy](http://www.trudicanavan.com/books/the-black-magician-trilogy/), possibly conflated with some elements of her [*Magician's Apprentice*](http://www.trudicanavan.com/books/the-magicians-apprentice/), whose plot is basically identical.

Comment: @randal'thor - argh you beat me by 5 minutes :( that'll teach me for trying to work at the same time as typing an answer and find evidence to back it up

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn I would've posted an answer if I hadn't repcapped for the day, but you're welcome to claim the glory :-)

Comment: @randal'thor thank you. most gracious

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Trudi Canavan *[The Black Magician Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Magician_(novel_series))* published between 2001 and 2003.

Magicians were able to drain magical power from other magicians through a cut using black magic, they could be drained to death.

I don't remember any of them exploding though *Cat'r'pillar* informs me they do if they still have power and this rings a faint bell now its been mentioned.

The books follow Sonea a young girl who learns she has magical ability as she is trained in the arts of magic. A lot of dueling, throwing magic at the shields goes on during her training.

She ends up falling in love with the with a fellow magician who teaches her Black Magic.

Comment: They explode when they have power remaining when they die, and it's released all at once or something like that.

Comment: @Cat'r'pillar cool, I can easily believe I forgot that fact it has been ages since I read them, have so many books in my head since then including all the ASOIAF books, Peter Hamilton's tomes and a bunch of Malazzan books, they all take up some serious memory space. It was the draining magic and throwing spells at each others shields that triggered my memory.

Comment: It just so happens that I reread the books very recently, or I wouldn't've remembered either :)